# Xcode 4 crashes after every "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" simulator or iPhone crash

Tags: iphone, xcode

Every time my app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS it causes Xcode to crash. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It sort of makes it difficult to debug when after every crash i don't get an error log I can look at and when I have to force quit and restart every time.

Comment: have you tried using the Leaks Instruments feature ?

Comment: The problem is that xcode crashes though, as in, i have to close it. Leaks wouldn't help stop that. And the solution is not to 'fix my app' because i need xcode working if i'm going to do that. And what happens when i add another feature and problems start occurring again? It's not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would uninstall Xcode 4 and uninstall Xcode 3. Then reinstall Xcode 3 (if you need it) first, then Xcode 4. Hope this helps!

Comment: Refer this beauty full tutorial http://www.techpaa.com/2012/03/finding-app-crash-and-fixing-them-easly.html